# Delphi ListView toggle item selected

Tags: listview, delphi

Is there a way to implement a toggle-like selection  mode for a TListView?

Clicking on an item, make it selected, click on another item make it selected as well. Clicking on the previous item, make it unselected and keeping the second one selected.

This does not seem to work:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; Change: TItemChange; var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
    ListView1.OnChanging := nil;
    try
        if Change = ctState then begin
            AllowChange := False;
            if NOT Item.Selected then begin
                Item.Selected := True;
            end else begin
                Item.Selected := False;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        ListView1.OnChanging := ListView1Changing;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: "This does not seem to work" without further description is rather useless. Anyway, the functionality you describe is a built in feature of the `TListView` with `ViewStyle = wsList` . If you set the `MultiSelect` property `True`, it works without any code. But you need to use `Ctrl` button when you select more than one item.

Comment: [Win32 > Design > List View > Usage patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-list-views#usage-patterns) describes this. You may to want read about the other controls, too.

Comment: "Unlike list boxes, they don't support multiple selection mode, where clicking any item toggles its selection state regardless of the Shift and Ctrl keys." So it seems toggle selection mode is not supported. I would exactly need the CTRL + Click mode without the CTRL. Ok thank you then. Half of the app. is based on a ListView instance using other component is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not give up that easily, the following code seems to work:

- Toggleing works
- SHIFT + click adds to selection
- Editing item caption works
- Cursor keys work (up/down), the code preserves previous selected state of the items

Set MultiSelect to True, tested with ViewStyle = vsReport.

```
var
  LastItem: TListItem;
  HotItem: TListItem;
  PreviousItemWasSelected: Boolean;
  ShiftDown: Boolean;
  CtrlDown: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Changing(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; Change: TItemChange; var AllowChange: Boolean);
var
    LVChangingEvent: TLVChangingEvent;
begin
    if CtrlDown then begin
        Exit;
    end;
    LVChangingEvent := (Sender as TListView).OnChanging;
    (Sender as TListView).OnChanging := nil;
    try
        if Change = ctState then begin
            if ShiftDown then begin
                if Item.Selected then begin
                    AllowChange := False;
                    Exit;
                end;
            end;
            if LastItem = Item then begin
                LastItem := nil;
                Exit;
            end;
            if Item.Focused then begin
                Item.Selected := NOT Item.Selected;
                LastItem := Item;
                Exit;
            end;
            AllowChange := False;
            if NOT ShiftDown then begin
                if HotItem <> Item then begin
                    Exit;
                end;
            end;
            if NOT Item.Selected then begin
                Item.Selected := True;
                Item.Focused := True;
                PreviousItemWasSelected := True;
            end else if Item.Selected then begin
                Item.Selected := False;
                PreviousItemWasSelected := False;
            end;
            LastItem := Item;
        end;
    finally
        (Sender as TListView).OnChanging := LVChangingEvent;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
    ListView: TListView;
    LVChangingEvent: TLVChangingEvent;
    CurrentNextSelected: Boolean;
begin
    if ssShift in Shift then begin
        ShiftDown := True;
    end;
    if ssCtrl in Shift then begin
        CtrlDown := True;
    end;
    ListView := Sender as TListView;
    if ListView.IsEditing then begin
        Exit;
    end;
    if Key = VK_DOWN then begin
        if NOT Assigned(ListView.ItemFocused) then begin
            Exit;
        end;
        if ListView.ItemFocused.Index = ListView.Items.Count - 1 then begin
            Exit;
        end;
        LVChangingEvent := ListView.OnChanging;
        ListView.OnChanging := nil;
        try
            CurrentNextSelected := ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index + 1].Selected;
            ListView.ItemFocused := ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index + 1];
            ListView.ItemFocused.Selected := True;
            ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index - 1].Selected := PreviousItemWasSelected;
            PreviousItemWasSelected := CurrentNextSelected;
            Key := 0;
        finally
            ListView.OnChanging := LVChangingEvent;
        end;
    end;
    if Key = VK_UP then begin
        if NOT Assigned(ListView.ItemFocused) then begin
            Exit;
        end;
        if ListView.ItemFocused.Index = 0 then begin
            Exit;
        end;
        LVChangingEvent := ListView.OnChanging;
        ListView.OnChanging := nil;
        try
            CurrentNextSelected := ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index - 1].Selected;
            ListView.ItemFocused := ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index - 1];
            ListView.ItemFocused.Selected := True;
            ListView.Items[ListView.ItemFocused.Index + 1].Selected := PreviousItemWasSelected;
            PreviousItemWasSelected := CurrentNextSelected;
            Key := 0;
        finally
            ListView.OnChanging := LVChangingEvent;
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    ShiftDown := ssShift in Shift;
    CtrlDown := ssCtrl in Shift;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
    HotItem := (Sender as TListView).GetItemAt(X, Y);
end;
```

But it seems there is a little issue that there is some kind of delay, maybe for the edit caption functionality, that quickly toggleing the same item is not possible. To toggle a specific item, a couple of 100 ms is needed to wait before the toggle.

If somebody has a nicer solution please share it! Thank you!